# How to wait for option to load - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've seen this question asked many times before but I've tried its suggestions but it doesn't seem to help. This is the site that I'm trying to go in https://www.iccf.com/tables, and I want to iterate through every "select category" option. So far I have this:

```
import selenium
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import shutil
from time import sleep
import traceback

PATH = '---'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www.iccf.com/tables')
   
categorys_1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders1'))))
categorys_2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders2'))))
categorys_3 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders3'))))
categorys_4 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders4'))))

for index_1 in range(1, len(categorys_1.options)):
    categorys_1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders1"))))

    categorys_1.options[index_1].click()
    print(categorys_1.options[index_1].text)
    
    for index_2 in range(1, len(categorys_2.options)):
        categorys_2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders2"))))

        categorys_2.options[index_2].click()
        print(categorys_2.options[index_2].text)

        
        for index_3 in range(1, len(categorys_3.options)):
            categorys_3 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders3"))))

            categorys_3.options[index_3].click()
            print(categorys_3.options[index_3].text)

                
            for index_4 in range(1, len(categorys_4.options)):
                categorys_4 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders4"))))

                categorys_4.options[index_4].click()
                print(categorys_4.options[index_4].text)
```

But I seem to be getting different errors when I run it multiple times with the same code, which leads me to believe that the errors are happening because I'm checking for options as the page is loading. But I put this line of code: `Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlHeaders2'))))`, I thought this would wait for the options to load then click them but I guess not, so how would you do so?

Just so you are aware, this site sometimes display 2 or 3 or 4 "select category" sections depending on what options you select.

Help soon is very appreciated.

Comment: include the exceptions you are receiving.  (I'm guessing stale element?)  The options could still be loading even though the select tag is there.

Comment: Yes, the error is stale element because it looks for the options before they load. I don't think an exception is necessary because in the exception that the program doesn't find the new options, I just want it to continue what its doing, there no particular different code that I want it to execute.

Comment: use your webdriverwait on the specific elements you want to interact with.  (in this case, the <option>s)  (You could also create a function that use findElements and catch stale element exceptions... if caught, you re-call the function.)

Comment: What ever, I'll just sleep a little, its not very solid but that's the only way that I can find which is possible.